# Free Microsoft Project Viewer for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-project

Does anyone have a freeware MS Project Viewer for Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one (the Light version of MOOS Project Viewer):
http://www.free-project-viewer.com/
It can also run directly from browser.

Comment: The Light version is free. The full version is shareware with 30 free trial.

Answer (score 3):

MOOS is just a 30-day trial

Try [RationalPlan Viewer](http://www.rationalplan.com/download.php), which looks similar (probably shares code with MOOS), but is free.

Note that it doesn't automatically associate itself with MS Project files; you have to specify "All Applications" when using "Open With > Other..." on a MS Project file. When opening a file from within Viewer, specify "Format: All ...".

Answer (score 0):

Found one:

> http://www.filebuzz.com/findsoftware/Free_Ms_Project_Viewer_For_Mac/1.html

Comment: http://www.rationalplan.com/download.php this is probably a better link.